# Update number on jQuery UI tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I have folders with tooltips such as '0 entries' or '5 entries' and so on. I need this tooltip number to update by 1 every time something is dropped into the folder. The title **doesn't always start at zero**, and I need $(this) drop div updated, as I have many. Here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4ehSG/3

**jQuery**

```
$(document).tooltip();

var dropped =0;

$( ".draggable" ).draggable();
    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        dropped++;
          $( this )
          .attr('title',dropped+' entries')
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
          $( ".draggable" ).fadeOut();
      }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="draggable ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div class="droppable ui-widget-header" title='2 entries'>
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what you can do: http://jsfiddle.net/4ehSG/9/

```
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
      var dropped = parseInt($(this).attr('title')) + 1;
      $( this )
      .attr('title',dropped+' entries')
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
      .find( "p" )
        .html( "Dropped!" );
      $( ".draggable" ).fadeOut();
  }
```

Comment: That is working nicely but the title doesn't always start at 0. Updated with a different and classes instead of ids. I have many drag and drop pieces, and need to update $(this) drop div. http://jsfiddle.net/4ehSG/3/

Answer (score 1):

You could increase a variable every time an element is dropped

try this

```
$(document).tooltip();
var num = 0;
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
        .find( "p" )
        .html( "Dropped!" );
        num++;

        $( "#draggable" ).fadeOut();
        $( "#droppable" ).attr("title", num + " entries");
  }
});
```

your updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/4ehSG/4/

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple instances of `droppable` and `draggable`, you may want to give each `droppable` an array associated with it.  That way you don't need to rely on a `count` object and you could drop the same `draggable` on multiple `droppable` objects.

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/EPptM/)

```
$(document).tooltip();
$( ".draggable" ).draggable();
$( ".droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        if(!$(this).data('droplist')){ //check for array
            $(this).data('droplist', []); //if doesn't exist, create array
        }
        var droplist = $(this).data('droplist'),
            drag = $(ui.draggable)[0];

        if(droplist.indexOf(drag) === -1) //check if element exists in array
            droplist.push(drag);

        $( this )
        .addClass( 'ui-state-highlight' )
        .find( 'p' )
        .html( 'Dropped!' )
        .end()
        .attr('title', droplist.length + ' entries');

         $(this).data('droplist', droplist); //set list
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ehSG/5/)

```
$(document).tooltip();

var count = 0;

$("#draggable").draggable();
$("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        count++;
        $(this)
            .attr('title', count + ' entries')
            .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
            .find("p")
            .html("Dropped!");
        $("#draggable").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
document.getElementById('droppable').title = value;
```

The above line of code is without using jQuery.

If you want to use jQuery, use the following:

```
$("#droppable").attr( 'title', value );
```